# Surjective functions proof f(a) = b

Tags: functions

My assumption is if we have to prove that a function is surjective we check for f(a) = b where a is an element of X (domain) and b is an element of Y (codomain)

considering this: if I have to prove that function `g: Z -> Z given by g(x) = 8x`

I would say is a surjective because:
by the choice of a and the definition of g(x)

- g(a) = 8a
- g(a) = 8 . b/8
- g(a) = b

But been told that g(x) is not surjective. which means my thought process is somewhere flawed.

Could somebody please explain to me what am I doing wrong in my explanation?

Comment: Notice that the domain of $g$ is $\Bbb Z$. Can you find an integer $a$ such that $g(a)=1$?

Answer (score 1):

The function in your example is defined according to the rule $n \mapsto 8n$,
with domain $\mathbb{Z}$ and codomain $\mathbb{Z}$. It is the collection of pairs $(n,8n)$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. The function is surjective if for every $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ there is $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $(n,m)=(n,8n)$, and the two pairs are equal if and only if $m=8n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. In other words, there are integers $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which there is no $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(n)=m$, so the function is not surjective. It is however injective: If $l,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ make two equal pairs $(l,8l)=(m,8m)$, then $8l=8m$ and so $l=m$. Thus $f(l)=f(m)$ means that $l=m$.

If, on the other hand, you consider the function $r \mapsto 8r$, with domain $\mathbb{R}$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}$, then you instead have a collection of pairs $(r,8r)$ where $r \in \mathbb{R}$. If you now pick an element $s \in \mathbb{R}$, and try to pair it according to $(r,s)=(r,8r)$, you have equality if and only if $s=8r$ for some $r \in \mathbb{R}$. The function is also injective: If $r,s \in \mathbb{R}$ make two equal pairs $(r,8r)=(s,8s)$, then $r=s$. An injective and surjective function is a bijective function.